# Composite component validation in JSF 2.0

Tags: validation, jsf-2, facelets, composite-component

I have composite component in JSF 2.0

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="inputId"/>
    <composite:attribute name="labelValue"/>
    <composite:attribute name="inputValue" />
    <composite:attribute name="required" />
    <composite:attribute name="requiredMessage" />
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
    <div class="control-group">
        <h:outputLabel for="#{cc.attrs.inputId}" value="#{cc.attrs.labelValue}" class="control-label" />
        <div class="controls">
            <h:inputText id="#{cc.attrs.inputId}" value="#{cc.attrs.inputValue}" required="#{cc.attrs.required}" requiredMessage="#{cc.attrs.requiredMessage}" />
        </div>
    </div>
</composite:implementation>
```

and I need to make some validation on it (is it number, lenght validation etc)
So, how can I make it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define the desired input for which you'd like to attach a validator as a [`<cc:editableValueHolder>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/composite/editableValueHolder.html) in the `<cc:interface>`.

```html
<cc:interface>
    <cc:editableValueHolder name="input" targets="#{cc.attrs.inputId}" />
    ...
</cc:interface>
```

The tag basically tells that any `<f:validator for="input">` must be applied on the `UIInput` component with the same `id` as specified in `targets`. So, you can then register it as follows:

```
<my:input ...>
    <f:validateLength for="input" ... />
</my:input>
```